# Is it possible to enforce input argument data types in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, types

I would like to ensure that the input arguments to a user-defined MATLAB function (contained in an m-file) are of a certain type. I understand that MATLAB automatically assigns data types to variables (to the liking of some and the dismay of others), but I would like to know if there is an option of "strict data typing" in MATLAB, or something of the sort, especially for input arguments for a user-defined function.

I found a helpful explanation of MATLAB's "fundamental classes" (data types) at these two webpages:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data-types_data-types.html

However, I have been unable to find an answer to the question of strict data typing, particularly for function input arguments. I thought it would be a pretty basic question that already had been answered in numerous places, but after extensive searching I have not yet found a conclusive answer. For now, I have been manually checking the data type using the `is[TYPE]()` functions and displaying an error message if it does not comply, though this seems sloppy and I wish I could just get MATLAB to enforce it for me.

Below is an example of a function in which I would like to specify the input argument data type. It resides in a file called `strict_data_type_test.m` in MATLAB's current path. In this function, I would like to force the variable `yes_or_no` to be of MATLAB's `logical` data type. I know I can use the `islogical()` function to manually check, but my question is if it is possible to have MATLAB enforce it for me. I also know that any non-zero double evaluates to true and a zero evaluates to false, but I want to force the user to send a `logical` to make sure the wrong argument was not sent in by accident, for example. Here is the example function:

```
function y = strict_data_type_test( x, yes_or_no )

    % manual data type check can go here, but manual check is not desirable

    if (yes_or_no)
        y = 2 .* x;
    else
        y = -5 .* x;
    end

end
```

Adding the data type before the input argument variable name (like in most programming languages) treats the data type text as another variable name instead of a data type identifier. From that it would seem that strict data typing is not possible in MATLAB by any means, but maybe one of you many gurus knows a useful trick, feature, or syntax that I have not been able to find.

Comment: The answer is no. What you call `is[TYPE]()` is the way to do it. Or read about the [`inputParser`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparserclass.html) class [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/input-parser-validation-functions.html). Or write a `mex` function if you like. What would you expect to happen if there were a type enforced and a user passed in the wrong type?

Comment: I agree with others that `inputParser` is the way to go. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20337956/2778484) for a summary and concise examples.

Comment: In response to horchler: I was hoping that if there was a type enforcement and a user passed in the wrong type from the console then an error would occur (without me having to manually program the error inside the function), and more importantly if a user was typing the function call inside another script or function then MATLAB would highlight the function call as an error, showing the user that it is incorrect without having to run the script/function ("compiler enforcement").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've gotten some great responses so I can't pick just one as the "accepted answer", but to summarize what I've learned from you all so far:

- **No, MATLAB does not have built-in strict data typing for function input arguments**
- MATLAB compiles the code before running, so manual validation checking should not be very taxing on performance (the profiler can be used to assess this)
- Many helpful methods of doing the manual validation checking exist, listed here in order of most relevant to least relevant for what I was trying to do:

  - [`inputParser` class](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparserclass.html)
  - [`validateattributes()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/validateattributes.html)
  - Error/exception handling (`throw()`, `error()`, `assert()`, etc.)
  - [MATLAB's built-in state detection functions (a.k.a predicate functions)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/is.html)
- I can look through some MathWorks-provided MATLAB functions (or Statistics toolbox functions) for ideas on how to validate input arguments by typing `edit` followed by the function name. Two suggested functions to look at are `normpdf()` (from the Statistics toolbox) and `integral()`. Some other functions I found helpful to look at are `dot()` and `cross()`.

Other thoughts:

- It would appear that the `inputParser` class was the overall concensus on the most professional way to validate input arguments. It was noted on [a related (but not duplicate) stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337956/2778484) that the newer MathWorks functions tend to make use of this class, suggesting that it may be the best and most up-to-date choice.
- Since the MathWorks-provided MATLAB functions do not appear to enforce strict input argument data typing, this further suggests that even if it was possible to do so, it may not be a recommended approach.
- MATLAB seems to regard "error handling" and "exception handling" as two different concepts. For example, here are two links to MATLAB's Documentation Center that show how MathWorks considers "error handling" and "exception handling" differently: [MathWorks Documentation Center article on Error Handling](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/error-handling.html), [MathWorks Documentation Center article on Exception Handling](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/exception-handling.html). A relevant StackOverflow post has been made on this topic and can be found [here (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886796/exceptions-vs-errors-in-matlab). I contacted MathWorks and added some new information about this topic to that post, so if you are interested you may read more by following that link.

Answer (score 6):

`validateattributes` might also work for you, if there is an appropriate attribute for your case.  For example if you want to enforce that yes_or_no is a logical scalar, you could try:

```
validateattributes(yes_or_no,{'logical'},{'scalar'})
```

Otherwise maybe an attribute like 'nonempty'.

Comment: You can use user-defined classes, so it works for any input type.  I use it frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab provides an 'inputParser' which allows to check inputs. Besides this you can use assertions:

```
assert(islogical(yes_or_no),'logical input expected')
```

To ensure the correct number of input arguments, use `narginchk`.

btw: Take a look in some Matlab functions like `edit integral` and check how tmw deals with this.

Comment: Is `edit integal` a typo? I found `edit` which seems to open files in an editor, and I assume `integal` is a typo for `integral`. So are you saying I should look at the code for the built-in MATLAB functions, such as `integral`, and see how those enforce input argument data types?

Comment: Yes, integal was a typo. For questions of architecture / patterns I often take a look at some built in function, supposing the designers of the language know how to use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may find writing this sort of code tedious or worry that it degrades performance:

```
if ~islogical(yes_or_no) && ~isscalar(yes_or_no)
    error('test:NotLogicalType','Second argument must be logical (Boolean).');
end
if yes_or_no
    y = 2 .* x;
else
    y = -5 .* x;
end
```

Recall, however, that Matlab compiles the code before running so even if you need to test many conditions it will be quite fast. Run the profiler to see.

Another option in some cases (maybe not your example) is to use a lazier method. This option lets your code run with whatever inputs were provided, but uses a [`try`/`catch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) block to trap any error:

```
try
    if yes_or_no
        y = 2 .* x;
    else
        y = -5 .* x;
    end
catch me
    ...
    error('test:NotLogicalType','Second argument must be logical (Boolean).');
    % rethrow(me);
end
```

The code above would produce an error if `yes_or_no` was a cell array for example (it will still allow non-Boolean, non-scalar, etc. values for `yes_or_no` though, but Matlab is often overly permissive). You can then either generate a custom error message, detect, what kind of error was thrown and try something else, etc. Many of the functions in the Statistics toolbox use this approach (e.g., type `edit normpdf` in your command window) for better or worse.

Comment: But the exception could also be thrown if `x` cannot be multiplied by `-5` (maybe it’s a graphics handle?).

Answer (score 0):

2019b introduced the `arguments` block: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arguments.html

From that link:
"Write a function that restricts the size of the input argument to a row vector of any length. Use a validation function to restrict the elements of that vector to numeric values."

```matlab
function [m,s] = twoStats(x)
    arguments
        x (1,:) {mustBeNumeric}
    end
    m = mean(x,"all");
    s = std(x,1,"all");
end
```